# ¿Ordenamiento de Nodos?

Tags: c++, c

Quisiera preguntar acerca del ordenamiento de nodos de una lista enlazada simple. Actualmente estoy teniendo problemas con el ordenamiento de una lista simple de un campo (`int`), quiero ordenar los nodos cambiando las relaciones entre ellos, he intentado de varias formas sin embargo a medida se “ordenan” ciertos nodos pierden la relación que tenían con otro nodo y queda fuera de la lista. Como pueden ver en el código ingreso los datos de forma LIFO (es decir que el último dato ingresado es el primero en la lista y así sucesivamente). Adjunto les muestro el código que tengo hasta ahora. ¿Podrian explicarme como hacerlo y quizas verlo en codigo?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Nodo
{
    int Dat;
    Nodo *Sig;
};

void InLIFO(Nodo*&,int);
void printlist(Nodo*);
void clearlist(Nodo*&);

void main()
{
    Nodo *L1 = NULL;
    InLIFO(L1,1);
    InLIFO(L1,2);
    InLIFO(L1,3);
    InLIFO(L1,4);
    InLIFO(L1,5);
    InLIFO(L1,6);
    printlist(L1);
    clearlist(L1);
        system("PAUSE");
}

void InLIFO(Nodo *&I, int D)
{
    Nodo *Nuevo = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    Nuevo -> Dat = D;
    Nuevo -> Sig = I;
    I = Nuevo;
}

void printlist(Nodo *I)
{
        for( ;I ; I = I -> Sig)
        {
            printf("%d\t",I -> Dat);
        }

}

void clearlist(Nodo*&I)
{
    Nodo *tmp;
    while(I)
    {
        tmp = I;
        I = I -> Sig;
        delete(tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué lenguaje estás usando? Todas las cabeceras y funciones son C, pero usas referencias (que son de C++). C y C++ son lenguajes distintos y cada uno de ellos puede ofrecer soluciones distintas. Por otro lado **te falta incluir tu función de ordenación** para que podamos ver qué podrías estar haciendo mal.

Comment: Tampoco estaría de más que pusieses un ejemplo de ordenación en el que se "_pierdan_" las relaciones... no queda demasiado claro ese punto.